# How did I calculate the power for this source?

Tags: power, circuit-analysis

**Let the circuit be:**

[image]

Given that I<sub>x</sub> = 5A and V<sub>y</sub> = 10V, calculate the power absorbed or delivered by each source.

**My solution:**

10A source delivers 100W (P=UI= (-10 + 20)x10 = 10 x  10 = 100W). ***Correct***

-10V source delivers 50W (P=UI= 10 x  5= 50W). ***Correct***

20V source  absorbs 100W (P=UI= 20 x  5= 100W). ***Correct***

0.5V<sub>y</sub> source  delivers 25W (10 = Ix + Iy, Iy = 10 - Ix = 10 - 5 = 5  *and* P=UI= (0.5V<sub>y</sub>)x Iy= 0.5 x 10 x 5) = 25W). ***Incorrect***

My teacher said that the dependent source 0.5V<sub>y</sub> **absorbs 50W**, while my answer is that it **delivers 25W**.

I couldn't figure out why my answer is wrong.

Comment: The circuit diagram is misleading. \$0.5V_y\$ is actually the magnitude of the current from the dependent current source (because of the "A" next to it to indicate Amperes), but you misinterpreted \$0.5V_y\$ as a voltage.

Comment: @Null, yeah. This is what happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a small miscalculation. The transfer function for the dependent current source is

$$
0.5\cdot V_y
$$

so if, \$V_y = 10\$, then the current through the source is 5A, multiplied for 10 V (\$V_y\$), is 50 W. The voltage polarity of \$V_y\$ and direction of current \$I_y\$, indicating that the source is absorbing power.

Comment: I misinterpreted 0.5Vy as a voltage. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The current Iy is 5A (5A = 0.5 \$\cdot\$ Vy A) ,  so the power is 5A \$\cdot\$ 10V = 50W.

Since current is flowing into the positive terminal, it is absorbing power.